# add_action second argument missing

Tags: hooks, actions

I don't know what is missing here. I have a **do_action()** and **add_action()**.

Only the first argument passed, to the function:

```
function testing($a, $b) {
    echo $a . $b; // Here is just get A, and an error for missing $b
}

$a = 'A';
$b = 'B';
do_action('test', $a, $b);

add_action('test', 'testing');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to say how many parameters your callback function needs. The default is 1, so WordPress will pass just `$a`. To get more parameters, use the fourth argument for `add_action()`:

```
add_action('test', 'testing', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thx, I promised myself i read those documentations carefully.. :)